# Como funciona sistema de grid?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

Estou utilizando **Bootstrap** num projeto, mas até agora não entendi como funciona a estrutura do mesmo. Ele utiliza grids mas [a documentação](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/) não é bem clara sobre como funciona e como utilizar.

Quero montar um layout que seja responsivo mas ao mesmo tempo quero saber o que estou fazendo. Sei que todas as frameworks de CSS utilizam grids, e gostaria de uma explicação de como funcionam e como utilizá-los para montar um layout.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### O que são grids CSS:

Grids CSS nada mais são que a "simulação" de uma estrutura tabular por meio de `divs`. Se você começou a mexer com internet na época de IE6 e afins, deve lembrar que tabelas eram muito utilizadas para estruturar layouts HTML. Isso se devia ao fato de ser mais fácil de trabalhar com layout em formato de grid na web, e a tabela tinha um comportamento parecido com uma grid (uma tabela de 10 linhas x 10 colunas simularia uma grid de 10x10).

O problema é que tabelas tem certas peculiaridades, como por exemplo o fato de não se darem muito bem com layouts responsivos (afinal, tabelas foram pensadas para se comportarem como estruturas "engessadas" desde o início), e semanticamente falando, não são recomendadas para o uso na construção do layout de uma página (como você acha que um leitor para cegos vai entender uma página que é toda feito dentro uma infinidade de tabelas, que estão sendo erroneamente utilizadas para montar layouts ao invés de mostrar dados tabulares?).

Junte estes fatores com o fato de layouts estarem se tornando a cada dia mais complexos e com um numero cada vez maior de dispositivos de todos os tamanhos com acesso a internet e fica evidente que layouts usando tabelas nunca foi e nunca seria a melhor solução disponível.

Foi então que os desenvolvedores perceberam que se eles conseguissem reproduzir a funcionalidade de grid de uma tabela, com a mobilidade e responsividade dos elementos de bloco (`divs`) isso facilitaria muito o processo de montagem de layouts, sendo a solução perfeita para finalmente subistituir as tabelas. Assim nascia o conceito de grids CSS.

Algumas das vantagens de se utilizar grids CSS são:

> - Semanticamente correto (elementos de layout sendo usados para layout);
> - Permite fácil estilização e maleabilidade;
> - Permite a reestruturação **total** dos blocos da grid de acordo com o tamanho do dispositivo (experimente redimensionar seu navegador
>     acessando o site do Bootstrap);

### Como usar grids CSS:

Como você mesmo disse na sua pergunta, praticamente todos os frameworks CSS vem com um sistema de grids com eles, e apesar de o nome das classes mudar, geralmente a estrutura é sempre a mesma (e inclusive vai te lembrar a estrutura de uma tabela):

```
[bloco-pai]
     |
     |----[linha]
     |       |
     |       |----[coluna]
```

Esta estrutura acima pode ser descrita em HTML como:

```
<div class="bloco-pai">
    <div class="linha">
        <div class="coluna"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Cada `bloco-pai` pode ter `n` linhas, e cada `linha` pode ter `n` colunas *(teóricamente, embora a maioria dos frameworks aceite um total de no máximo 12 ou 24 colunas)*

Como você pode perceber, a estrutura de uma grid CSS é bem parecida com a estrutura de uma `table`, vou mostrar um exemplo:

```
<table> <!-- equivalente ao bloco-pai -->
    <tr> <!-- equivalente a linha -->
        <td></td> <!-- equivalente a coluna -->
    </tr>
</table>
```

Depois que você entende que a estrutura de uma grid CSS nada mais é que o equivalente a estrutura de uma `table`, fica muito mais fácil de entender o que você está fazendo no código.

Pois bem, e se eu quiser trabalhar com grids CSS, mas usando colunas com tamanhos distintos?

É aí que entram aquelas classes *com nomes estranhos* do Bootstrap:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estas classes, quando adicionadas em uma **coluna** definem um tamanho específico para ela, o que seria o equivalente ao `colspan` nas tabelas.

Então vamos a mais um exemplo, desta vez usando o Bootstrap:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8"></div> <!-- Esta coluna terá um tamanho de 8/12 -->
        <div class="col-md-4"></div> <!-- Esta coluna terá um tamanho de 4/12 -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Como você pode ver, a estrutura básica acima vai gerar uma "grid" com uma linha e duas colunas, uma de tamanho 8/12 (66.66%) e outra de tamanho 4/12 (33.33%).

Lembrando que os tamanhos das colunas geralmente nunca são definidos em `px` (pixels), mas sim em `%` (porcentagem), de forma que eles sempre assumem uma porcentagem do tamanho do elemento pai acima deles.

Isto significa que se você criasse um elemento pai com uma largura de `1000px` e adicionasse duas colunas com tamanho `6/12` (ou seja, 50%) dentro dele, essas colunas assumiriam `500px` de largura cada uma. Caso o tamanho do elemento pai fosse modificado para `500px`, ambas as colunas agora teriam `250px`, e assim por diante.

Bom, grids CSS possuem muito mais vantagens e detalhes extras que se fossem ser escritos aqui iam acabar gerando uma resposta maior do que esta já está, então deixo o resto como lição de casa para você ler lá na [documentação do Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

---

**Bonus:**

Para quem não sabe, existe um padrão de grids CSS sendo especificado pela W3C, e *-pasmen-*, o IE10+ já implementou a funcionalidade. [Vale a pena dar uma olhada](http://loopinfinito.com.br/2013/10/08/css-grid-isso-muda-tudo-de-novo/).

Answer (score 5):

Apesar de eu considerar a documentação bem completa, vamos lá.

[Sistema de Grid Bootstrap Oficial (Inglês)](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

O bootstrap trabalha dividindo a tela em 12 colunas.
Independente de qual dispositivo você esteja utilizando, ele utiliza 12 colunas.

Os dispositivos que ele dá suporte são 4:

**Tela muito largas (Telas com tamanho superior ou igual a 1200px):** *col-lg-*

**Tela largas (Telas com tamanho superior ou igual a 992px):** *col-md-*

**Tela pequenas (Telas com tamanho superior ou igual a 768px):** *col-sm-*

**Tela extremamente pequenas (geralmente celulares) (Telas com tamanho de até 767px):** *col-xs-*

Assim sendo se quiser construir uma area em sua tela que utiliza 9 colunas para o conteudo a sua esquerda, e 3 para menu a direita. Você deve definir isso dentro de um *.container* e dentro de uma *.row* veja o exemplo para telas largas:

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-9">Conteúdo</div>
          <div class="col-md-3">Menu</div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Daí, você precisa ir estudando, seguindo esse conceito e vendo o link que postei, onde você vai começar a entender melhor.

Existem vários videos no youtube ensinando também a utilizar o Bootstrap:
[Building with Bootstrap(Inglês)](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEEQtwIwAg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DYXVoqJEwqoQ&ei=70AfU4XGBoqEkQegsYGICw&usg=AFQjCNGLRXINIVKVoL4VtK-NwBfhalUWIA&sig2=Ra4bMKxUAn5v-JafD2nvtw&bvm=bv.62788935,d.eW0)

Este é apenas um deles... 
Lembrando que a maioria das matérias estarão em inglês já que em pt-br só tem estimadamente 10% de todo conhecimento tecnológico traduzido.
Mas fica ai, qualquer coisa, só entrar em contato.

Answer (score 5):

O grid system funciona com classes que incluem uma largura para os seus elementos. Sendo de 1 até 12. A modo que 12 é a largura máxima de sua página.

Logo
`<div class="col-md-12"></div>` #Representa uma div que terá a largura máxima da sua página.
`<div class="col-md-6"></div>` # Representa metade de sua página.

Então se a largura máxima são 12 e você quer 2 divs em 1 linha, logo:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6"></div><div class="col-md-6"></div> # 6 + 6 = 12
</div>
```

Entendendo a classe:
**col** - Colunas
**md, xs, sm** - Dispositivos que terão a medida
**1 ate 12** - Tamanho da largura

Logo, eu posso usar:

`<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12"></div><div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12"></div>` # 6 + 6 = 12

Isso significa que em telas desktop terei 2 colunas de 6 e em extra small terei 2 colunas com 12, elas aparecerão 1 por linha no caso do xs.

Espero não ter sido vago, mas a documentação é mais explicativa. Basta estudar um pouco mais :)

Answer (score 3):

Por padrão, o *Bootstrap* cria uma grid com colunas cujo tamanho é 100% do container pai. Por exemplo, se você quer colocar uma grid num espaço de 960 pixels (uma `<div>`, por exemplo), o *Bootstrap* irá gerar uma grid que ocupe harmoniosamente este espaço.

O que eu acho que pode gerar alguma confusão é na numeração (`.col-md-3`, `col-md-4`). Isso é por causa do [sistema 960 de grids](http://960.gs/), que é um padrão da internet em que a média de tamanho dos displays dá mais ou menos 960 pixels. A ideia é dividir sua grid em no máximo 12 colunas, e cada número destes representa o espaço em número de colunas mínimas que ocupa.

No primeiro exemplo temos uma grid de uma linha e 3 colunas, com a classe `col-md-4`. Ou seja, são 3 colunas de tamanho 4, ou seja, que ocupam o espaço de 4 colunas mínimas.

Os demais exemplos são análogos.