# Duvidas e Mais duvidas sobre o bootstrap 3 Layout

Tags: html5, twitter-bootstrap, layout-responsivo, grid

Olá estou ccomeçando agora com o bootstrap e é o meu primeiro contato com layout responsivo estou tentando criar algo assim: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas não consigo deixar tudo encaixado não estou conseguindo fazer nada alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Cara será que ai num seria uma questão de css não ? Além de usar o bootstrap, acho que poderia fazer as colunas ficarem assim no css mesmo...

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa de um container, com rows e colunas dentro, seria algo como:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">ESQUERDA</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">centro</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">DIREITA</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Sugiro que dê uma lida na documentação oficial, ou  [Nessa versão traduzida para o portugues e *levemente* desatualizada](http://alexanmtz.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html) . Caso queira um playground para testar seu código, pode usuar o [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/new)

Edit: Para tornar o container fluido, altere a classse do container para `container-fluid`.

Answer (score 2):

A estrutura HTML ficaria assim:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-7"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Exemplo: [**`FIDDLE`**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dxgxa/embedded/result/)

Obs.: Caso você queira aprender mais sobre o sistema de grids do Bootstrap, [essa minha outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8894/como-funciona-sistema-de-grid/8920#8920) pode te ajudar.