# Campos na mesma linha Bootstrap aplicação MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, bootstrap

Gostaria de uma dica de como colocar dois campos na mesma linha no Razor, usando o bootstrap em uma aplicação ASP.NET MVC5.

```
div class="ibox-content">
                            <form role="form" class="form-inline">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nm_EquipeMinima, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nm_EquipeMinima)
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nm_EquipeMinima)
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nr_EquipeMinima, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nr_EquipeMinima)
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nr_EquipeMinima)
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div class="ibox-content">
```

Este é o meu código e abaixo o resultado.

[image: imagem da dúvida]

Answer (score 2):

No Bootstrap, tenha em mente que o todo espaço é divisível por 12 ou múltiplos de 12.

Quando você faz:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nm_EquipeMinima, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nm_EquipeMinima)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nm_EquipeMinima)
    </div>
</div>
```

Seu `form-group` ocupa os 12 espaços. Seu `label` ocupa 2 espaços (`@class = "col-md-2"`) e seu `@Html.EditorFor` ocupa 6 espaços (`div class="col-md-6"`). Ainda sobrariam 4 espaços para colocar mais alguma coisa na linha.

A forma de fazer isso é colocando todos os componentes dentro do mesmo `form-group`, assim:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nm_EquipeMinima, new { @class = "control-label col-md-1" })
    <div class="col-md-5">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nm_EquipeMinima)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nm_EquipeMinima)
    </div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nr_EquipeMinima, new { @class = "control-label col-md-1" })
    <div class="col-md-5">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nr_EquipeMinima)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nr_EquipeMinima)
    </div>
</div>
```

Repare que tenho dois `label` com `col-md-1` e duas `div` com `col-md-5`. Seria 1 + 1 + 5 + 5 = 12. Ou seja, coloco assim todos os campos na mesma linha ocupando os 12 espaços disponíveis pelo *framework*.

[Veja uma explicação sobre o sistema de grids aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8894/como-funciona-sistema-de-grid/8920#8920).

Answer (score 2):

Erison, fiz algumas pequenas alterações no seu html, onde adicionei um div com class `row` e os divs onde eram `form-group` coloquei `col-md-6`, acredito que isso seja o suficiente no seu caso.

Você pode ver melhor sobre o uso dos `col-...` no [link](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)

```
<div class="ibox-content">
    <form role="form" class="form-inline">
        <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nm_EquipeMinima, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nm_EquipeMinima)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nm_EquipeMinima)
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nr_EquipeMinima, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nr_EquipeMinima)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nr_EquipeMinima)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Nas `divs` de dentro, ainda tem mais 4 espaços cada que podem ser utilizados. Desta forma fica meio feião porque os blocos ficarão alinhados à esquerda.

Comment: mas o label fica em cima do input, então seria só mudar o div col-md-6 para 12 e tirar o form-inline ai fica bonitão :)