# Sistema de Grid Framework CSS

Tags: css, bootstrap, framework, materialize

sou novo no ramo de Framework CSS, minha dúvida é o seguinte.
Independente de ferramenta (Bootstrap, Materialize , etc) como é o processo de criação de um site usando grid CSS? Não o funcionamento da grid em si, mas a aplicabilidade na prática, as documentações não falam sobre isso.
Por exemplo, a grosso modo era assim (acredito eu):
O programador fazia vários layouts para vários dispositivos, o script identificava o dispositivo e então apresentava o layout adequado. Hoje sabemos que não é assim, mas como criar um layout já pensando nos dispositivos diferentes ? O Framework faz isso sozinho? Ele vai renderizar tudo sozinho? No processo de criação eu devo seguir o raciocínio acima (de criar vários layouts) e ir testando com as colunas especificadas para o dispositivo? Qual o fluxo de criação ?
Desculpe se foi muito longa a pergunta e se foi confusa rrss.. Obrigado !

Comment: Se já analisou alguma tela que usa boostrap, verá que dentro das class nas tags HTML existem vários nomes como `col-sm-12`. Isso representa o tamanho da grid, ele vai se adaptando com o tamanho das telas e dispositivos devido as bibliotecas CSS e JS que vem junto com o Bootstrap. [Aqui vai ter mais informações sobre Bootstrap.](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp)

Comment: A resposta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/8920/3635 parece que responde bem ao problema, explica que ao redimensionar os grids já se auto-atualizam conforme você configurou previamente e explicar como usa-los. Se falta algo comente por favor.

Answer (score 1):

Vou explicar usando bootstrap como referência pois é o framework que eu melhor conheço.

Ele divide qualquer espaço dentro de um elemento em 12 colunas não importando o tamanho total do elemento, ou seja:

```
<body> // eu tenho 12 colunas dentro do body
    <div> // eu tenho 12 colunas dentro da primeira div
        <div> // eu tenho 12 colunas dentro da segunda div
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

A questão da responsividade entra quando marcamos quantas colunas um elemento tem de largura para determinado tamanho de tela.

- Temos a marcação de coluna `col-lg` de 1 a 12 para telas grandes
- Temos a marcação de coluna `col-md` de 1 a 12 para telas médias
- Temos a marcação de coluna `col-sm` de 1 a 12 para telas pequenas
- Temos a marcação de coluna `col-xs` de 1 a 12 para telas mobile

Exemplo:

```
<div id="pai">
    <div id="div1" class="col-lg-10 col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
    <div id="div2" class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
</div>
```

- Em uma tela grande, o `filho1` vai ocupar `10` colunas do `pai` enquanto o `filho2` vai ocupar `2` colunas do `pai`.
- Em uma tela média, o `filho1` vai ocupar `8` colunas do `pai` enquanto o `filho2` vai ocupar `4` colunas do `pai`.
- Em uma tela pequena, o `filho1` vai ocupar `6` colunas do `pai` enquanto o `filho2` vai ocupar `6` colunas do `pai`.
- Em uma tela mobile, o `filho1` vai ocupar `12` colunas do `pai` enquanto o `filho2` vai ocupar `12` colunas do `pai`.

E como ele sabe qual coluna ele deve aplicar para o tamanho da tela?

É graças a um recurso chamado [Media query](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) que você pode aplicar determinado css para um tamanho de tela que você deseja.

Exemplo, tirado do próprio código fonte do bootstrap 3 sem alterar nada:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12 {
        float: left;
    }
    .col-sm-12 {
        width: 100%;
    }
    ...
}
```

Até que a tela na qual o website for aberto não tenha o tamanho de no mínimo `768px`, que é o tamanho que o bootstrap considera para telas pequenas, as classes `col-sm-` não respondem para não sobrescrever os estilos das classes de telas mobile, os `col-xs-`. Pois conforme maior a tela, as classes correspondentes a tamanhos maiores vão sobrescrevendo as classes de tamanhos menores.

Ta, beleza. Isso não responde sua pergunta se o Framework vai fazer o trabalho de pensar em varias telas ou não.

A resposta é não. Você ainda precisa pensar no seu layout para multi-telas, o framework vai te facilitar em transitar entre elas sem ter de ficar redirecionando seu usuário para vários layouts e principalmente, sem ter de dar manutenção em vários arquivos de layout.

Ele te possibilita adaptar o layout para várias telas sem ter de remontar/reordenar elementos. Apenas usando as classes você consegue trocar elementos de posição/coluna conforme você transita de uma tela para outra, você pode determinar que o elemento X não vai aparecer para telas mobile enquanto o elemento Y vai aparecer apenas no mobile.

Tudo isso usando apenas as classes do [sistema de grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) e [classes utilitárias](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)

Lembrando que há casos que usar um framework css com sistema de grid não vai satisfazer suas necessidades por completo, então não se sinta obrigado a usar um só por que o mercado usa.

Espero ter conseguido te esclarecer um pouco da vantagem de se usar um sistema de grid.

Comment: A resposta esta boa, mas recomendo que acaso já tenha uma pergunta com resposta sobre o assunto o melhor é marcar a pergunta como duplicata usando o link [Sinalizar] que fica abaixo da pergunta, pois se não começa a ter vários conteudos repetidos e espalhados sobre o mesmo assunto, entenda como uma critica construtiva ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu nem procurei uma pergunta ou resposta relacionada, eu simplesmente botei meu conhecimento a prova pra tentar ajudar o cara, numa próxima pergunta generalista desse eu dou uma procurada antes. Bobiei haha

Comment: Uma dica: sempre olhe os comentários nas perguntas, geralmente o pessoa já aponta links para duplicatas ;) Até mais

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu ja estava escrevendo a resposta quando o pessoal fez os comentários. Só vi os comentários quando terminei a resposta. Quando comecei a responder não tinha nem essa outra resposta ai de baixo.

Comment: tinha um comentário do Renan (ele apagou) a mais de 60 minutos, mas sim as vezes isso ocorre, como disse é uma dica e não uma critica ... Seja bem vindo a comunidade, aparece no chat pra jogar uma conversa fora, até mais ;)